# OBIEE: creating dynamic Dashboard Title based on data return

Tags: obiee

### Date | Cost Price | Selling Price

10/10/2015 | 200 | 280

I already have my dates from the prompt showing on my dashboard in OBIEE. I want to add another scenario to the Title display so It becomes dynamic.

How can I dynamically show Profit on the title when a user selects a date?
eg. "In 10/10/2015, you made a profit of 280"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have that in the title, but you can place a narrative view just below it to display the information.

If "Date" is the first column of your analysis and "Selling Price" is the third one, the code you need to write in the "Narrative" section of your narrative view will be like this:

```
In @1, you made a profit of @3
```

I strongly recommend you put 1 in the "Rows to display" field of the narrative view even if your analysis returns only 1 row.

I hope this helps you.